# Find the branching factor in a tree given the total number of nodes in the tree

Tags: trees

Suppose I know the number of total employees and the number of levels in the company hierarchy.

Assuming that the number of subordinates a supervisor has is constant across the levels, how can I find the average number of subordinates per manager (branching factor) the company has?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you do it if there are two levels?  Three levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say there are $n$ nodes. Then it can be anywhere between $n - 1$ (a root and $n - 1$ children) and $1$ (just a path of $n$ nodes).

You can argue similarly for several levels. Say you have exactly $k$ levels, that means a root (1), with $c$ children, each of those has $c$ children in turn ($c^2$ in all), ..., at level $k - 1$ there are $c^{k - 1}$ nodes in all. Thus:

$\begin{align*}
   1 + c + c^2 + \dotsm + c^{k - 1}
     &= n \\
   \frac{c^k - 1}{c - 1}
     &= n \\
   c^k - 1
     &= n (c - 1)
\end{align*}$

This you'll have to solve numerically.